# HTML include script with jsx, es2017 tags and other tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, ecmascript-2017

I have the following Javascript (JSX, es2017, and others) that works fine when included on a page, but when I fetch the content from a url in a `src` tag, it's no longer functional. How can I include the following when the source is from another file?

I cannot load my Javascript when imported from a `src` tag:

```
<script src="...some_url..." type="text/jsx" data-presets="es2017,react,stage-0" data-plugins="transform-decorators-legacy"></script>
```

However the following works when included on the page.

```
<script type="text/jsx" data-presets="es2017,react,stage-0" data-plugins="transform-decorators-legacy">
function test(div_id) {
        const {LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;
        const data = [
              {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
              {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
              {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
              {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
              {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
              {name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500},
              {name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100},
        ];
        const SimpleLineChart = React.createClass({
                render () {
                return (
                <LineChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
                    margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
               <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
               <YAxis/>
               <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
               <Tooltip/>
               <Legend />
               <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
               <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
              </LineChart>
            );
          }
        })

        ReactDOM.render(
                <SimpleLineChart />,
                document.getElementById(div_id)
        );
}
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use [babel standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone). Take a look and check you've followed the instructions correctly. For example, you have a typo: `data-presents` should be `data-presets`. I'm not sure why you need it as the code you've got in your question is just basic JS that can be exported/imported readily without it.

Comment: I updated my question for my specific use case. I'm not sure if this relates to the update. Thanks for the help!